# Mongoid text_search taking too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Yesterday I reindexed my collection. It has over two million documents.

Searching through a Mongodb client (robomongo) I have results in little time:

```
db.items.find({$text: {$search: "The Long Haul"}})
```

http://cl.ly/image/182B1P2D1h2n

However, performing a search with Mongoid text_search:

```
Item.text_search(term).execute
```

query takes forever (over 2 minutes) (some other searches through text_search take much less time).

```
D, [2014-12-19T17:56:07.598777 #66067] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 22.22.22.22:43700 COMMAND      database=production command={:text=>"items", :search=>"\"The\"\"Long\"\"Haul\""} runtime: 131198.9850ms
OVER
131.199424
```

Does [text_search](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo:text_search) perform the query any different from the "raw" text search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know if you figured this out, but I ran across your question while looking for reasons Mongoid `.text_search` does not work in MongoDB 3.0. 
The current MongoDB docs recommend running queries on a text index like this from the shell;

```
db.items.find({$text: {$search: "The Long Haul"}})
```

The Mongoid .text_search method uses the `text` command that has been removed in 3.0.  Here is an example from the shell,

```
db.items.runCommand( "text", { search: "The Long Haul"} )
```

This may explain the performance difference between your two queries.

Incase it will help, the following syntax works from Mongoid on Mongodb 3.0;

```
Item.where({ :$text => { :$search => "The Long Haul"} } )
```

Comment: Thanks. I moved to Elasticsearch (w/ searchkick), but that answers my question :)

Comment: I think this is the closest to full text search you will get: Item.where({ :$text => { :$search => "The Long Haul"} } )